# How to write file names in a zip file to a txt file using loops?

Tags: python, loops, zip

I have written code to the point where it can write all of the file names to the console but I want to be able to write the file names inside of the zip to a text file. I am reusing the code that I used to write the names into the console. I am having trouble (By trouble I mean that I receive an error saying 'not writable')however writing the file names in my zip file (called FileTest.zip) to a separate file which is in the txt format(named file.txt).

```
import zipfile

write_file = open('file.txt')

file_names = zipfile.ZipFile('FileTest.zip','r')
for name in file_names.namelist():
    write_file.write('%s' % (name))
file_names.close()
write_file.close()
```

Comment: You should probably `open` your file in write mode. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Perhaps from the terminal just type: `unzip -l ./myfile.zip > names.txt`; and forget Python all together, if you are on a *nix system, or have the GNU `unzip` tool installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in write mode:
`open('file.txt', "w")`.
Note that this will overwrite the file. If you want a different option, look here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Your code could be refactored like so:

```py
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('FileTest.zip','r') as archive:
    with open("file.txt", "w") as f
        for name in archive.namelist():
            f.write('%s' % (name))
```